# Table rows count always is 0 sql server with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, dataset, rows

I have a project using dataset in VS2012.
I create the database with sql server. I create a table as LeagueInfo and type some rows.
It's OK until I use C# to get `League.Rows.Count` that alway return 0.
So what can I do?

```c#
var dataset = new LeagueDataSet(); // LeagueDataSet inheritance form DataSet class
DataTable table = dataset.Tables["LeagueInfo"];
int row = table.Rows.Count; // It's alway return 0 even I have data in table
```

Comment: What happens if you use the line var table = dataset.Tables["LeagueInfo"];

Comment: I used that. and the same result. I had some missing in code above . I had edited @DB101

Comment: Is a number returned if you do a dataset.tables.count?

Comment: Actually - how are you instantiating your LeagueDataset object? Is the connection string pointing to a concretete SQL Server or to a model?

Comment: table doesn't has Count property

Comment: It's automatic when I add create database. I'm sure connection string is correct because my dataset detected correct table

Comment: Did you put this `LeagueInfo` table in DataSet (Drag and drop)?

Comment: That may be so, but if you are connecting to a model that is recreated every time you run your project, it will always be empty unless you populate it via code. Can you run a SELECT @@SERVERNAME query against your database from your c# code? This will allow us to see what the connection is being made to. Otherwise, without seeing your code for LeagueDataSet, It is going to be all guess work.

Comment: I think I did @Darka

Comment: So open LeagueDataSet and look if this table exist there :)

Comment: thanks everybody for help

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for help.
I know
 what I have to do:

```C#
            var adapter = new LeagueDataSetTableAdapters.LeagueInfoTableAdapter();
            var table = adapter.GetData();
            var x = table.Rows.Count;
```

When create database or table, Visual Studio auto creates some controller as `LeagueInfoTableAdapter`,
and I have to get data from that instead of directly.